# Authenticating to GKE master in Python

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to authenticate to a Kubernetes cluster provisioned in [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) using the [Kubernetes Python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client) and the Google Cloud python client. I would prefer not to shell out to `gcloud` for several reasons:

- relying on the system shell `gcloud` in a Python script when I have a native Google Cloud library is inelegant
- it requires the system to have `gcloud`
- I would have to switch users to the relevant ServiceAccount and switch back
- It incurs the cost of starting/joining another process

As such, the workflow of `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` (which delegates to `gcloud config config-helper`) will not suffice to get me the API key I need. How do I get the equivalent output with the Google Cloud Python API?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import kubernetes.client
import googleapiclient.discovery
import base64

# get the cluster object from GKE
gke = googleapiclient.discovery.build('container', 'v1', credentials=config['credentials'])
name = f'projects/{config["project_id"]}/locations/{config["location"]}/{parent}/clusters/{config["name"]}'
gke_clusters = gke.projects().locations().clusters()
gke_cluster = gke_clusters.get(name=name).execute()

# set up Kubernetes Config
kube_config = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
kube_config.host = 'https://{0}/'.format(gke_cluster['endpoint'])
kube_config.verify_ssl = True
#kube_config.api_key['authenticate'] = "don't know what goes here"

# regretably, the Kubernetes client requires `ssl_ca_cert` to be a path, not the literal cert, so I will write it here.
kube_config.ssl_ca_cert = 'ssl_ca_cert'
with open(kube_config.ssl_ca_cert, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.decodestring(gke_cluster['masterAuth']['clusterCaCertificate'].encode()))

# use Kubernetes client to do something
kube_client = kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration=kube_config)
kube_v1 = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api(kube_client)
kube_v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a solution that pulls the access token out of the googleapiclient, rather than copy-pasting things manually.

```py
import googleapiclient.discovery
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import kubernetes
import base64

def token(*scopes):
    credentials = googleapiclient._auth.default_credentials()
    scopes = [f'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/{s}' for s in scopes]
    scoped = googleapiclient._auth.with_scopes(credentials, scopes)
    googleapiclient._auth.refresh_credentials(scoped)
    return scoped.token

def kubernetes_api(cluster):
    config = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
    config.host = f'https://{cluster["endpoint"]}'

    config.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'
    config.api_key['authorization'] = token('cloud-platform')

    with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as cert:
        cert.write(base64.decodebytes(cluster['masterAuth']['clusterCaCertificate'].encode()))
        config.ssl_ca_cert = cert.name

    client = kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration=config)
    api = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api(client)

    return api

def run(cluster):
    """You'll need to give whichever account `googleapiclient` is using the 
    'Kubernetes Engine Developer' role so that it can access the Kubernetes API.

    `cluster` should be the dict you get back from `projects.zones.clusters.get`
    and the like"""

    api = kubernetes_api(cluster)
    print(api.list_pod_for_all_namespaces())
```

Figuring this out took longer than I care to admit. @Ivan's post helped a lot.

Comment: Is the google token meant to be a valid kubernetes token? I mean if it works great... But is this documented somewhere? In case it gets 'deprecated' in future.

Comment: It's been six months, but I think I came up with this by inspecting gcloud's code. Searching now, I can't find anything on bearer token auth with GKE, so I'm gonna say 'undocumented'.

Comment: See the following docs for info. From the docs, "All GKE clusters are configured to accept Google Cloud user and service account identities..."

[GKE docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication)

Also, would recommend using this method to retrieve the credentials:
[Python client auth docs](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.auth.html#google.auth.default)

Answer (score 2):

In order to authenticate to a GKE cluster, you can use a [service account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#service-account-tokens) to connect to a project and then a generated secret key from GKE to authenticate to a cluster. Here are the steps:

1. Create a service account in GCP. Go to IAM > Service Accounts > create a service account. Give it a Project Owner role. Once SA is created, create a key and download it as json.
2. Upload key.json to a folder where you have .py script
3. Get API_TOKEN. This is your main question, you can get it by reading a token file:

   - First run `kubectl get secrets`
   - You will get ‘default-token-xxxxx’
   - run `kubectl describe secrets default-token-xxxxx` (replace xxxxx with your token name).
   - The token parameter displayed is your “API-KEY”. Copy it inside your script.
4. Creating a script. It is a bit different then yours for few reasons: you need to authenticate to a project first with a service account, then you need to pass the api_token, but also you need to get SSL certificate when authenticating to GKE master.

```
import base64, pprint
import kubernetes.client
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("key.json")
gke = googleapiclient.discovery.build('container', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
name = 'projects/your_project/locations/your_zone/clusters/your_gke_cluster'
gke_clusters = gke.projects().locations().clusters()
gke_cluster = gke_clusters.get(name=name).execute()

kube_config = kubernetes.client.Configuration()
kube_config.host = 'https://{}'.format(gke_cluster['endpoint'])
kube_config.verify_ssl = True

kube_config.api_key['authorization'] = 'your_api_token'
kube_config.api_key_prefix['authorization'] = 'Bearer'

kube_config.ssl_ca_cert = 'ssl_ca_cert'

with open(kube_config.ssl_ca_cert, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.decodestring(gke_cluster['masterAuth']['clusterCaCertificate'].encode()))

kube_client = kubernetes.client.ApiClient(configuration=kube_config)
kube_v1 = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api(kube_client)
pprint.pprint(kube_v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces())
```

Specific fields:

- your_project - from GCP
- your _zone - where gke cluster is created
- your _gke_cluster - GKE cluster name
- your_api_key - what you get in step 3.

This should be enough to authenticate you to a GKE cluster.

Comment: Note that I had to apply a `ClusterRoleBinding` to the default user in order to actually use the API.