# Creating short-lived credentials from a GCP service account in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm aware of 2 ways to create a short lived scoped authentication token from a GCP service account, using two different google libraries:

1. googleapiclient._auth.with_scopes()
2. google.auth.impersonated_credentials.Credentials()

Each has its own (dis)advantages:
The latter requires the service account in question to have the "service account token creator" role. The former does not. (Why is it so?)
On the other hand, the second method allows for a lifetime longer than one hour (if "iam.allowServiceAccountCredentialLifetimeExtension" constraint is set accordingly)

What are the other differences between the two methods?

I tried to find a method that combines the best of the two methods above, namely being able to specify token lifetime beyond 1 hour, but without having to grant the token creator role.
Is that achievable?

P.S. The first method is not very well documented. I got it from Andy Jones's reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410410/authenticating-to-gke-master-in-python).

Edit:
As commented by John Hanley, the proper (and documented) way to use first method is using google.auth.service_account.Credentials.with_scopes()

To summarize, there are 2 ways to create a short lived token:
Once we have created Credentials from a service account file, we can scope them for our intended purpose ("with_scopes()") and then call refresh(Request()) in order to generate a valid token. This token is valid for an hour.

Instead of using the scoped credentials directly to generate a token, we can create a new instance of credentials from them by constructing google.auth.impersonated_credentials.Credentials from them, specifying desired lifetime. Then we call refresh(Request()) on this instance to create the short lived token for up to 12 hours.

The disadvantage of the second method is that it requires that the service account has the "Service Account Token Creator" role.
In addition, "constraints/iam.allowServiceAccountCredentialLifetimeExtension" has to be set in the policy

Comment: It's absolutely not the same thing! The first option take the default credential on  your runtime environment. The second one, take the default credential on your environment and create a new credential on a service account, as long as the default credential has the servie account token creator on it. At the end, you have a token either on your default credential (can be your user credential) or on a service account by impersonation (can be only a impersonated service account, not a user account.)

Comment: If you do not have a Google Cloud Organization you cannot specify an expiration time longer than 3600 seconds. You should use the recommended library `google.oauth2` https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html.