# How to write a Cloud Function to fetch Kubernetes deployments names by authenticating to GKE cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a Cloud Function USING PYTHON in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) that fetches the names of deployments from a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster. I want the Cloud Function to authenticate to the GKE cluster and retrieve the deployment names programmatically.

Here's what I need assistance with:

How do I authenticate the Cloud Function to the GKE cluster securely?
What libraries or tools should I use to interact with the GKE cluster from the Cloud Function?
Can you provide a sample code or guide on how to write the Cloud Function to fetch the deployments' names from the GKE cluster?
Are there any best practices or considerations I should keep in mind while implementing this solution?
Any help or guidance on the above points would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**How do I authenticate the Cloud Function to the GKE cluster securely?**

You should use service accounts with proper role and permission to be able to communicate with GKE API / Cluster. You may look at this [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication#applications_within) to help you get started.

**What libraries or tools should I use to interact with the GKE cluster from the Cloud Function?**

Based on this [github discussion](https://github.com/googleapis/python-container/issues/6#issuecomment-582168539) you need to use the following libraries to be able to authenticate with the GKE, you can follow it as well:

```
from google.cloud import container_v1
from kubernetes import client as kubernetes_client
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import base64
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests
```

**Can you provide a sample code or guide on how to write the Cloud Function to fetch the deployments' names from the GKE cluster?**

You may look the following articles / discussions that you can follow to write your python code.

- [Authenticating to GKE master in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410410/authenticating-to-gke-master-in-python)
- [Python method for gcloud container clusters get-credentials #6](https://github.com/googleapis/python-container/issues/6#issuecomment-582168539)

**Are there any best practices or considerations I should keep in mind while implementing this solution?**

- Implement your Service Accounts roles/permission with the concept of [least privelege](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/least-privilege-for-cloud-functions-using-cloud-iam).
- Make sure Make sure the subnet where your GKE resides should have [Private Google Access enabled](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-google-access).